# can not enter keyboard configuration

Tags: release-freya, settings, keyboard

[image: Before system settings is closed]

When I click the keyboard configuration, The system settings was closed.

[image: Segmentation error?]

/usr/bin/gnome-control-center: line 20:  4487 Segmentation error (core dumped) switchboard $switchboard_options $requested_plug

Comment: Try a reset.
Instruction are here

http://askubuntu.com/questions/395/how-do-i-reset-my-keyboard-layout